# Parsing Java String with SGML

Tags: java, parsing, sgml

I have a Java String with SGML, something like this...

```
<misspell></misspell><plain>I</plain> <plain>know</plain> <plain>you</plain> <suggestion>ducky</suggestion> <plain>suck</plain> <plain>and</plain> <plain>I</plain> <plain>rocky</plain> <plain>rock</plain>
```

How do I parse it to get for instance say the text inside `<suggestion> </suggestion>`so as to get "ducky" out??

Will javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parse can be of any help? or I can only parse HTML docs with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you show is not HTML, but it could be parsed by [an XML parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-parsers).

The [SAX API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html) is part of the JDK and AFAIK most XML parsers implement it.

Comment: Its just a plain String.Will the SAX API(javax.xml.parsers) work?

Comment: @Myth, from the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html): "XML can be parsed from a variety of input sources. These input sources are InputStreams, Files, URLs, and SAX InputSources". And it seems to be possible to construct an InputSource using a StringReader.

Answer (score 1):

try an html parser, they are (by necessity) quite forgiving of malformed markup and html is by nature based on SGML.

e.g. http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/