# Parse sgml file

Tags: java

I need to parse sgml files in Java . Below is the content in sgml file I need the FILING-DATA, CIK and ASSIGNED-SIC. Please help me in this regard.

```
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20130226172602
<ACCESSION-NUMBER>0001193125-13-077271
<TYPE>10-K
<PUBLIC-DOCUMENT-COUNT>15
<PERIOD>20121231
<FILING-DATE>20130226
<DATE-OF-FILING-DATE-CHANGE>20130226
<FILER>
<COMPANY-DATA>
<CONFORMED-NAME>COGNIZANT TECHNOLOGY SOLUTIONS CORP
<CIK>0001058290
<ASSIGNED-SIC>7371
<IRS-NUMBER>133728359
<FISCAL-YEAR-END>1231
</COMPANY-DATA>
<FILING-VALUES>
<FORM-TYPE>10-K
<ACT>34
<FILE-NUMBER>000-24429
<FILM-NUMBER>13643872
</FILING-VALUES>
<BUSINESS-ADDRESS>
<STREET1>500 FRANK W. BURR BLVD.
<CITY>TEANECK
<STATE>NJ
<ZIP>07666
<PHONE>2018010233
</BUSINESS-ADDRESS>
<MAIL-ADDRESS>
<STREET1>500 FRANK W. BURR BLVD.
<CITY>TEANECK
<STATE>NJ
<ZIP>07666
</MAIL-ADDRESS>
</FILER>
</SEC-HEADER>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Are you working on text categorization?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these stuffs
[**Simple SGML parser**](http://standardcode.eu/programming/java/simple-sgml-parser.html)
**[SGML parser in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867894/sgml-parser-in-java)**
[**SAX-like API for SGML (SGML parser for Java)**](https://code.google.com/p/sasgml/source/browse/trunk/src/ar/com/rjgodoy/sgml/sax/SGMLReader.java?spec=svn2&r=2)

Comment: If you have any issue with the latter, just ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a very old post and OP might get the solution but there is no useful reference. I am not claiming that answer provided by me is perfect or best solution but it served the purpose and I was able to successfully get the data from very large SGML files also. So I hope it may help someone in need to parse SGML file.
Kindly refer to my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867894/sgml-parser-in-java/5220503#answer-46314846)
Kindly let me know in case any clarification required.